# How to get whether iPhone's camera is facing down the earth or facing up the sky

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-location, core-motion

Hi i need to know whether is there any way to find iPhone's camera position that is facing down the earth or facing up the sky.i need it since i am working on some proof of concept. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take the device orientation.. and you have there:

   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown

   [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDeviceOrientation][1]

   [1]: http://device%20orientation%20values
2. You can also use phone accelerometer for a more precise
   orientation..but i think it's more than enough using
   UIDeviceOrientation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIDevice`'s `orientation` property (once you've started generating the orientation notifications):

```
[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Later...

```
switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown: 
        // Do things
}
```

Or, for more precise notifications, you can use Core Motion and check the `attitude` property, but that gets a bit more complicated.